# Vagrant cannot install RVM on Windows

Tags: windows, rvm, vagrant

I am having an issue installing RVM on an Ubuntu VM using vagrant via Windows.
RVM says that I need to change my terminal emulator to allow login shell, and I have no idea how to do this. Here is a screenshot of the message from RVM.

http://s21.postimg.org/4k1s4ojaf/Capture.png

Comment: Afaik RVM is not designed to function under the normal Wndows cmd.exe - you may need e.g. cygwin with bash.

Comment: how do you login to the ubuntu vm? do you ru nany extra commands to login to the user?

Comment: I just use vagrant ssh...

Answer (score 0):

after you login run:

```
rvm get head --auto-dotfiles
```

and relogin, do not modify shell initialization files manually

Comment: Can you please explain what this does? How can I script the relogin part, as I want to run all of this from a Vagrantfile?

Comment: have a look on https://github.com/rvm/rvm-binary - after https://github.com/rvm/rvm-binary/blob/master/install-ruby.sh - you can: `source $( rvm "$1" do rvm env --path )` - where `$1` was given in https://github.com/rvm/rvm-binary/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L29